# Target a div to insert content after

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to insert some html content between pages of a rendered PDF.
The structure is the following:

```
<div class="page" data-page-number="1" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="2" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="3" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="4" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>
```

How can I target page 3 (or page 69)?
They have all the same class and differ only by "data-page-number".

Thank you

Edit:
I need to do something similar to:

```
node = document.getElementById('........');
node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div> ... </div>');
```

Targeting specific pages.

Edit:
So I did...

```
if (document.body.contains(document.querySelector('.page[data-page-number="72"]'))) {

node = document.querySelector('.page[data-page-number="72"]');

node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div> ... </div>');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector `.page[data-page-number="{number}"]`, which targets all elements that have the `page` tag with the `data-page-number` attribute set to `{number}`:

```js
var selected = document.querySelector('.page[data-page-number="3"]');
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<div class="page" data-page-number="1" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="2" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="3" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>

<div class="page" data-page-number="4" style="width: 1031px; height: 1459px;" data-loaded="true"></div>
```

Comment: With your solution, can I do something similar to this:

node = document.getElementById('........');
node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div> ... </div>');

Comment: @AndreaDeDonatis Yes, you 100% can.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Spectric's answer, you can dynamically create your selector string whenever you want:

```
let selectorString = '.page[data-page-number=' + num + ']'; 
var selected = document.querySelector(selectorString);
```